# vue prop is always the default value inside child comp

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-props

i am passing a bunch of props from parent to child component.
inside my child component, i defined a default value for all props.

`Overview.vue (child)`

```js
  props: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },
    title: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },
    username: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      default: ''
    },
    phone: {
      type: Number,
      default: null
    },
    status: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      default: ''
    },
    statusOptions: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    }
  },
```

my parent looks like this:

`UserSettings.vue (parent)`

```html
          <overview
            :name="name"
            :username.sync="username"
            :email="email"
            :status="status"
            :status-options="statusOptions"
            @update-username="username = $event"
          />
```

`UserSettings.vue data (parent)`

```js
  data() {
    return {
      name: 'John',
      username: 'Nevermind',
      email: 'john.nevermind@okey.com',
      status: 'idle',
      statusOptions: ['idle', 'vacation', 'working']
    }
  }
```

inside my child comp i want to save the passed data inside my `data()` like this:

`Overview.vue (child)`

```js
  data() {
    return {
      overviewData: {
        username: this.username,
        email: this.email,
        phone: this.phone,
        status: this.status
      }
    };
  },
```

problem now is, inside my child component in `overviewData` all my props are set to default and it is not taking the passed prop value.

Comment: Please also add parent code for setting the data

Comment: added the data from parent

Comment: At first glance all looks well. It could be some sort of caching issue. Try refreshing the page. If that doesn't work, put some console logging in both `data` functions to confirm that it's running the latest code. Also try changing the defaults to something other than empty strings, see if the values still match the defaults.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is an error with the way you are displaying data in `<overview>` (or otherwise determining that it is blank). See working sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-http-iymn4?file=/src/components/Overview.vue). Please feel free to edit with overview implementation so that we can get you sorted.